# compile only \ref

Tags: cross-referencing

Is there a simple way to process a `.tex` file so that only the `\ref` commands are processed?  I.e., replace `\ref{bla}` with `(1)` (or whatever numbering is correct) but leave all the rest untouched?

I have a convoluted way of doing that from the `.aux` file, but I'd rather a more systematic approach if it exists.

NOTE: Previous question asked for `\label` too, but that may be too complicated as pointed out in the comments.

Comment: Let's assume that `\label{bla}` occurs inside the first `equation` environment of the document. (That's why `\ref{bla}` is supposed to return `1`.) If TeX must "leave all the rest untouched", as you put it, how is TeX supposed to be able to evaluate `\label{bla}` and `\ref{a}`? At a minimum, the instructions associated with `\begin{equation}` and `\end{equation}` would have to processed, no? For without such processing, how is TeX supposed to "know" which counter variable is going to be incremented, and what the value of the incremented counter might be?

Comment: `\label` doesn't typeset anything at all, so what exactly are you trying to do and to what purpose? Right now, your question is very unclear - to me, at least.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you'd like to transform the source `.tex` file, to eliminate all `\label` and `\ref` commands, by replacing them with whatever will produce identical output when the resulting `.tex` file is recompiled. Is that correct? If so, I'm afraid that TeX (especially when LaTeX is involved) is not so great at working with the `.tex` source, so I doubt there are any great approaches… maybe you can post your own convoluted approach as an answer, so that it can be helpful to others and be a starting point for better solutions. Also, it may help to explain why you want this.

Comment: I have edited this to ask only for \ref, which should be easier.  This is for putting .tex on wordpress (e.g., on my blog).

Comment: Why would you even want to do so?  Once you make the substitution in the `.tex` file, you lose the ability to reverse the process, and if you have to add a new equation, table, or figure, you are left cursing like a user of MSWord, having to manually adjust all numbers?

Comment: Have you tried [latex2wp](https://lucatrevisan.wordpress.com/latex-to-wordpress/)? It already supports `\label` and `\ref`.

Comment: Last I checked it doens't do things I need, such as bib.

Comment: I think the best bet would be to post your convoluted method (or at least a sketch of it). It has a good chance of inspiring others to think along the right lines :-)